# pgRouting TSP with eventual order constraints?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

Is-it possible to run Travelling Sales Person (TSP) in pgRouting (I've got 2.3... installed) with constraints?

A general TSP algorythm or those I've identified in pgRounting solve the TSP
problem visiting each nodes (cities) to create the shortest cost path at the end.

I need a more sophisticated solution that enables adding constraints
before the calculated related to node (city) order.

Eg.: Say we have 5 points to reach like A B C D and E.

In a regular TSP when starting from A it would answer **A -> D -> E -> C -> B** [-> A].

Let's assume that we have a package to carry meanwhile from C to E, so C must precede E on that day of traveling.

So, a constraint comes up like: C -> E

The full definition of the call would be:

Do TSP with

- A B C D E

  - Starting from A (and also finishing here)
  - CONSTRAINT: visit C before E (and maybe more...)

Is there a solution, algorithm, program like this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange ! Please add more context, documentation, links, etc. I've done a little search on web and found : http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/src/tsp/doc/pgr_eucledianTSP.html#pgr-euclediantsp . Is that answer your question ? I think not, it's not so simple, so, add more context.

Comment: To J. Monticolo: There is plenty of context, no need to ask for documentation (?), links etc. pgRouting doesn't support that kind of optimization, only basic TSP. I develop and sell a software package called FleetEngine, which supports more complex constraints. OP can have a look at it, if he likes too.

Comment: pgRouting has an optimization function VRP with Time Windows. Could that help? https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/pgr_gsoc_vrppdtw.html#pgr-gsocvrppdtw